# url rewrite: same structure diffent query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are looking to keep the same url structure but different query strings

e.g

```
RewriteRule ^deals/(.*)/(.*)\/$ /handset.php?handsetname=$2&manufacturer=$1 [L]  = /deals/$manufacturer/$handsetname/
```

we would like the same url structure to  display the handset family which would look like this but at the moment it conflicts with the first rule

```
RewriteRule ^deals/(.*)/(.*)\/$ /handsetfamily.php?handsetfamily=$2&manufacturer=$1 [L] 
=/deals/$manufacturer/$handsetfamily/
```

We are looking for a rule which will allow us to accommodate both url queries

Comment: Both rules have the same regex pattern, so by default  the first rule matches.

Comment: is there a way to query different pages with the same structure?
For example this site seems to do it ..... 
http://xxxx.com/deals/Apple/iPhone-6/  and http://xxxx.com/deals/Apple/iPhone-6-64GB/

Comment: /apple/iphone-6 and /apple/iphone-6-64GB Are these dynamic paths?

Comment: yes, both dynamically generated from a database. I don't know the query string though.

http://mobilecontractcomparison.com/deals/Apple/iPhone-6/
http://mobilecontractcomparison.com/deals/Apple/iPhone-6-64GB-Silver/

Unless there is some coding tricks I cant see here